# Why does my Kaggle notebook look like JSON

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I think I've broken my Kaggle notebook:   When I open the notebook in Kaggle, what I see on the screen is the JSON that represents the notebook contents rather than the notebook itself.  Apparently, it's not *completely* clobbered, since I can download it as a .ipynb file, and when I open that file in a local copy of Jupyter, it looks as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, OK, I just clicked on [Edit] and now the notebook looks like a notebook.